# setCharacterEncoding method not encoding properly with iso-8859-15 for special characters

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I have simple form submit flow, the requesting is going throw the filter before it is receiving by Servlet. In my doFilter method the first line itself is setting the Character Encoding with **iso-8859-15** as shown below

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException {
    servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("iso-8859-15"); //encoding setting
```

In my request object, I have a parameter called "name" which is holding value as "**1Depósito**" (i.e. International language special characters). The parameter value is modifying once **setCharacterEncoding** method executes. The parameter value is encoding to "**1DepÃ³sito**" instead of "**1Depósito**"

In my parameter value we have a special character **"ó"** (i.e. ASCII code 243) because of this it is not encoding properly but I believe **iso-8859-15** is supporting **"ó"** character so then why it is not encoding properly?

In my request header the charset is showing as UTF-8

So in my filter if i change my encoding to **"UTF-8"** from **"iso-8859-15"** then it is working fine but I need to work with "iso-8859-15" only because the same code is working in my other tomcat build.

**NOTE:**

- 1) Migrated into Spring-Boot and running on tomcat --> here the iso-8859-15 encoding is applying properly even the input request charset is “UTF-8”
- 2) Normal WebLogic build --> here the iso-8859-15 encoding is not applying properly even the input request charset is “UTF-8”
- In **fiddler** I have debugged the incoming we request and observed that both requests (Tomcat & WebLogic) charset having no difference (i.e. Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8)

Kindly confirm that is "iso-8859-15" is supporting **"ó"** characters? if yes, then why encoding is not working?

Looking forward to your valuable inputs.

Thanks,
BSK

Comment: The request is coming in as `UTF-8`. That's why you get that result when forcing `ISO-8559-15` as the encoding. The client has decided to send you UTF-8 data, so forcing it to something else will only corrupt the values. What do you mean by "I need to work with iso-8859-15 only"?

Comment: Thanks for quick comment.
So you mean the request content in UTF-8 so the encoding must be UTF-8?

I need to work with iso-8859-15 means I don't want to change the code at my backend/server side.

Comment: I mean the request is already in `UTF-8` and it's too late to change it at where you're trying to change it. You either need to modify the encoding of whatever is sending the data, such as adding an `accept-charset` attribute to a form, or just accept the data as is. I mean it works if you don't try to change the encoding of the request, doesn't it? It only broke when you started to fiddle around with the encoding.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman.

Yes, in my request head I could see the below value so the request is receiving in UTF-8 format

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

So as per your inputs, either change charset in the HTML form before submitting or don't apply any other encoding at server side.

Comment: I think your premise is incorrect 'only as the special character "ó" is valid for "iso-8859-15"'. [U+00F3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm) is present in many character sets, obviously including Unicode. UTF-8 is an encoding for Unicode. Both the browser and the server seem to be handling UTF-8 just fine. In a Java string, the encoding is UTF-16. Presumably, it has the value you need. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Tom, Thanks for update.
How could it fix at java end without changing the encoding charset?

Comment: I think if you remove `.setCharacterEncoding()` then everything "should just work". Does it? Why do you think you need an old character set like ISO-8859-15? [Unicode has included](http://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-15.TXT) all of its characters since at least 1999.

Comment: Tom,
I have 2 versions of same application. 1) running with Spring-boot embedded tomcat server 2) running in WebLogic. When the request is submitted in WebLogic build the encoding is not happening correctly but in  spring-boot based tomcat build doing job correctly. In both the cases the request charset is UTF-8 only.